# Recent (?) novel about the UK going back to medieval times?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I only read the synopsis a few months ago in a recommendation list online and wanted to find the book again.

**What I'm sure about**: The plot was basically that the current day UK or England decides (or is forced by an extremist group of citizens) to go back to a very traditional society, medieval age style, without technology.

**Additional info I think I remember but take it with a grain of salt:**

- The change was done by a political group that had enough of today's society
- The title might have the word "age" in it, the one that I think I remembered was Dark Age but it's obviously not the right book.
- The synopsis had some religious theme in it as if religion was the new deciding order or the main antagonist was a religious person.
- This book was maybe recommended in one of those "books to read while in lockdown"
- It felt like it was fairly recent (maybe it was in a 2018-2020 books recommendations)

It is not the Handmaid's Tale as it was happening in the UK/England and technology was also forbidden and it is not Peter Dickinson's Changes Trilogy (the change of society was a decision, not an accident, and I don't think it was a children's book).

Comment: My first reaction to this premise is that most of the current population of the UK would quickly starve to death if they weren't allowed to use powered machinery, chemical fertilizers, etc., to grow the necessary amount of food. Unless they were maintaining good trade relations with the rest of the world and importing something like 95 percent of their food from countries that used modern farming methods?

Comment: True, but I don't see how that helps identify the story.

Comment: @tardigrade Two points: 1) It was just a spur-of-the-moment thought which popped into my head and I decided to post it. 2) It could very well prompt Caravage's memory to come up with more details, such as "millions of citizens fled the UK when the Medieval Fundamentalist Regime took over, thereby reducing the need for fresh food," or "yes, millions of citizens had recently died from a pandemic, and the Medieval Fundamentalist Regime took over on the grounds that this had been the Wrath of God for all the sinful technology people had been using." Details which might help someone ID the story?

Answer (score 2):

It could be The Second Sleep by Robert Harris.  It's recent and has a UK that's gone back to medieval style religious control.